# Удаление товара

Tags: javascript

есть магазин в котором присутствуют товары, нужно сделать так что б при удалении товара появлялось окошко в котором будет написано: 
Товар был удален, если это была ошибка, нажмите кнопку «Отмена»
у пользователя есть 20 секунд что б нажать отмена, в противном случае по API посылается запрос на удаление.
моя проблема в том что я не знаю как сделать так что б при попытке обновить страницу или закрыть браузер, отправлять запрос не дожидаясь 20 секунд

```js
function deleteProduct() {
  var $alert = $('<div class="error-messege"><h2>УДАЛЕНИЕ</h2><p>Товар был удален, если это была ошибка, нажмите кнопку «Отмена»</p><button class="cancel">Отмена</button>');
  $(".error-container").append($alert);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $alert.fadeOut(10000);
  }, 10000);
}
$("#click").click(function(){
  //тут должен начатся отщет времени 20 сек либо закрытие браузера, после которого отправляется XMLHttpRequest(), а при нажатии отмена действие отменяется
  deleteProduct();
}
);
```

```css
.error-messege {
  width: 336px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1c2942;
  color: #ce4d76;
  padding: 22px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.error-messege h2 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'FranklinGothicDemi';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5pt;
}
.error-messege p {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="click" value="УДАЛИТЬ ТОВАР">
<div class="error-container"></div>
```

Comment: Можете использовать *`$( window ).unload(function(){})`* чтобы при закрытии браузера или вкладки в т.ч. досрочно послать запрос на удаление.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, суть вкратце:
1. Удаление делаете в таймере
2. Таймер выводите в переменную, и по отмене очищаете

```
var delTimer;
function deleteCancel() {
  if( delTimer ) clearTimeout(delTimer);
}
function deleteProduct() {
  var $alert = $('<div class="error-messege"><h2>УДАЛЕНИЕ</h2><p>Товар был удален, если это была ошибка, нажмите кнопку «Отмена»</p><button class="cancel" onclick="deleteCancel()">Отмена</button>');
  $(".error-container").append($alert);
  delTimer = setTimeout(function() {
  //тут должен начатся отщет времени 20 сек либо закрытие браузера, после которого отправляется XMLHttpRequest(), а при нажатии отмена действие отменяется
    $alert.fadeOut(10000);
  }, 10000);
}
$("#click").click(function(){
  deleteProduct();
}
```

Не проверял, идею должны уловить ;)